# display the value of all selected radio buttons on a form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I have multiple radio buttons generated in a php loop which looks something like this

```
while(){

     <input type="radio" id="picks'.$x.'" name="picks['.$x.']" value="'.$row['team1'].' " onclick="return disp()""><span>'.$team1.'</span>

   <input type="radio" id="picks'.$x.'"  name="picks['.$x.']" value="'.$row['team2'].' "onclick="return disp()""><span>'.$team2.'</span>

    <input type="radio" name="picks'.$x.'" value="draw" onclick="return disp()">

}
```

[image]

**What I want to do**

Display all selected radio buttons in a div on the bottom of page

**My Code**

```
var elmnts = document.getElementById("makePicksForm").elements
var lngth = document.getElementById("makePicksForm").length;
var div = document.getElementById("dispPicks");

for (var x = 0; x < lngth; x++) {
    if (elmnts[x].type == "radio" && elmnts[x].checked == true) {
        div.innerHTML = elmnts[x].value;
    }
}
```

**My Problem**

Only the value of **first selected** radio button is displayed in div, other radio buttons are ignored

[image]

**My Question**

Any idea how I can modify my javascript to display the values of ALL selected radio buttons?

Comment: I guess you need checkbox instead. Radio button is designed to allow only 1 selected in a group.

Comment: note: your PHP loop creates duplicates ID's. This could result in javascript failures at some point

Comment: @KhanhTO the whole point is to allow only 1 selected in a group, you cant select more than 1 winner

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you've tagged your question with jQuery, here is a jQuery solution. Run the snippet to see it work:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(':radio').change(function (e) {
        //clear the div
        $('#dispPicks').html('');
        //update the div
        $(':radio:checked').each(function (ind, ele) {
            $('#dispPicks').append($(ele).val() + '<br/>');
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="radio" name="foo" value="foo1" />
<input type="radio" name="foo" value="foo2" />
<input type="radio" name="foo" value="foo3" />
<br/>
<input type="radio" name="bar" value="bar1" />
<input type="radio" name="bar" value="bar2" />
<input type="radio" name="bar" value="bar3" />
<br/>
<input type="radio" name="wow" value="wow1" />
<input type="radio" name="wow" value="wow2" />
<input type="radio" name="wow" value="wow3" />
<div id="dispPicks"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks Ted but it is not working, remove checked attribute in your fiddle and when I select a radio button no value is displayed...

Comment: @TimothyCoetzee I updated my answer and included the snippet here. Run it to see it work.

Comment: Thank you soooo much, you have no idea how much I appreciate this. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You're using `lngth` in your for loop, but that's defined by getting an element by ID which should only be 1 element. Your loop will only run once that way...

Assuming the element with ID `makePicksForm` contains all your radio buttons, you need to get the length of the elements:

```
var elmnts = document.getElementById("makePicksForm").elements;
var div = document.getElementById("dispPicks");

for (var x = 0; x < elmnts.length; x++) {
    if (elmnts[x].type == "radio" && elmnts[x].checked == true) {
        div.innerHTML += elmnts[x].value;
    }
}
```

Also, you need to add the value to the innerHTML property, using `+=`

as a side note: your PHP loop is creating duplicate ID's, which will result in failures in your javascript code if you need to reference the elements...

Comment: This leads to the same problem i have, only 1 selection displays! When user moves on to the next group of radio buttons the previous selection gets over written with new selection instead of appending it...I have given you an upvote for your trouble though Thanks

Comment: Ah, you need to add the value to the innerHTML using +=. I updated my example

Answer (score 1):

Another [jQuery-Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Gunnar/0u3zccg6/)

```
<input type="radio" id="bob" name="boys" value="Bob"><label for="bob">Bob</label><br>
<input type="radio" id="jim" name="boys" value="Jim"><label for="jim">Jim</label><br>
<input type="radio" id="pete" name="boys" value="Pete"><label for="pete">Pete</label><br>
<input type="radio" id="mary" name="girls" value="Mary"><label for="mary">Mary</label><br>
<input type="radio" id="jane" name="girls" value="Jane"><label for="jane">Jane</label><br>
<input type="radio" id="susan" name="girls" value="Susan"><label for="susan">Susan</label>

<h3><span id="boy">?</span> and <span id="girl">?</span></h3>

$("input[name=boys]").click(function () {
    $("#boy").text($(this).val());
});

$("input[name=girls]").click(function () {
    $("#girl").text($(this).val());
});
```